# laravel js best practice

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm writing a Laravel 5.3 app using it's default layout, and I'm wondering which is the best practice for adding an external js library.

Should I have to put the js file directly in public/js, or there is another cleaner way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I usually add my external libraries, like jQuery in public/js as it is more natural to use in my view layout, as Laravel implicitly references your public directory for such assets.

Comment: It was my way of doing it, but now I'm exploring the Laravel way https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/elixir (I'm a little bit confused on where to put the files...)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is-

Directory structure

```
  Public
    |
    |-js
       |-script.js
    |-css
       |-style.css
```

To call libraries call `asset()` helper

```
<script src="{{ asset('/js/script.js') }}"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also put everything is the public directory public/js etc, but sometimes I create sub directories to keep thing easy and orderly. Then you can call

> `asset('js/widgets/mywidget.js').`

I do a similar thing with css and siteicons.